# How to perform scheduled backups on parse.com?

Tags: database, backup, parse-platform, database-backups

Do you have any suggestions for backing up a parse.com database regularly?

Information about this are quite scarse, and I'd like to perform something similar to the manual export data function in the dashboard, but daily.

Does anyone have a script or something like this that they would like to share?

Parse said they were going to think about this feature but a year has passed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To backup your Parse data, you simply would need to get all the records for every Parse Class that you have.  For this example, I'll borrow from the [Parse REST API documentation](https://www.parse.com/docs/rest).  Parse has SDK's for [JavaScript](https://www.parse.com/docs/js_guide), [.NET](https://www.parse.com/docs/dotnet_guide), and [iOS/OS X](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#top/iOS), all of which provide a similar functionality to what is described here.

To get records from a Parse Class called 'GameScore', you could do something like:

```
curl -X GET \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: <YOUR APPLICATION ID>" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: <YOUR PARSE REST API KEY>" \
  -G \
  --data-urlencode 'limit=1000' \
  --data-urlencode 'skip=4000' \
  https://api.parse.com/1/classes/GameScore
```

Here `limit=1000` means you are going to get 1000 records at a time (the biggest amount possible), and `skip=4000` means we want to skip the first 4000 records.  Basically you would just repeat this command, starting with `skip=0` and incrementing `skip` by 1000 every time until the number of records that comes back is less than 1000 (no more records left).  Rinse and repeat for all of your Parse Classes and your data will be backed up.

Comment: I'm going to mark this as solved, but I think that perhaps I'm better off writing a small script that can log in to parse and press export data.. :)

Comment: I know that this is parse's mantra on backing up our data, but sadly this strategy (and even parse's own export functionality) completely ignores any attempts to ensure data integrity (especially referential integrity).  That is, this way we're not creating a snapshot of the data, but instead we're creating a random pull of records over a relatively random period of time...

Comment: There's a 10k skip limit so this method is useless unless you only have very small tables.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue of backing up parse server data. As parse server is using mongodb that is why backing up data is not an issue I have just done a simple thing. downloaded the mongodb backup from the server. And then restored it using

`mongorestore /path-to-mongodump` (extracted files)

As parse has been turned to open source.Therefore we can adopt this technique.

Comment: yes it saves each and every thing which is in the database.
In my case whatever I can see in parse dashboard was successfully backed up

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [bash script](https://github.com/meirka/parsebackup) I made for parse platform backup.
The script might need a bit adjustment based on OS.